# Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0...Watch.app is missing its app extension

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios9, watchos-2

I'm having a problem with an iPhone only app that I started working on when iOS6 was the current iOS. So except for a Today Extension that I added with iOS8 it is all Objective-C. The Extension is Swift though.

I upgraded the app to iOS9 and took care of all warnings and errors so that it worked fine.

Then I just added a WatchKit2 app/extension and left all the defaults untouched. I had it built and run. While it compiled successfully the simulator wouldn't launch with the this error message:

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)"

I read through all the articles that deal with this error and the all seem unrelated to my specific problem. I looked up the log files and got the more detailed error message:

> com.apple.dt.Xcode[7296] : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError
>   Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=WatchKitTwoAppMissingExtension,
>   ErrorDescription=WatchKit 2 app at
>   /Users/dirk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/22412FCA-09DB-4578-88B3-436FED290AAD/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.wsIJih/extracted/xxx.app/Watch/xxxWatch.app
>   is missing its app extension.}

Right at the end it says

> "..xxxWatch.app is missing its app extension".

Now both targets the app and extension are there. I spent hour going through the `info.plist` and build settings but everything seems ok.

Not sure what additional information to share to get you started.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem now :(...  thxs!

Comment: Nope, I had to take a entirely different approach to complete my task :(

Comment: I see... Could you please tell me what that approach was? I've been struggling with this for a while :(

Comment: Not sure I can help you as may task is likely to be different from yours. But you may want to check out this [link](https://github.com/doertydoerk/Garage/blob/master/GarageWatch%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift) and the function in line 108 (checkServer()) On high level I'm calling this function first before I invoke the actual HTTP request to make sure the server is alive. I only enable the user button if the checkServer() functions returns 200 for HTTP status code. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this comment is unrelated.

Comment: @Leslie, I don't think there's a direct message option. If there was I wouldn't have to respond here.

Comment: For me I had added the watch app to an existing project. The incorrect extension was configured in my project for the watch app target. I was using a project wide extension setting. Once I had removed it, the watch app was configured correctly. Remember to always delete your derived data after making a project change. THIS IS IMPORTANT. Xcode bug. Otherwise your changes won't be applied.